# nginx + slim location block setting

Tags: nginx, slim

I'm now trying to setup a new location block for a new api with the following directories and files:
rootDir
--api1.php
--api
------lib
--------v1
----------api2.php

here is my nginx.conf location blocks:

```
location / {
        #root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api1.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ /api/lib/(\w+)/ {


        include        fastcgi_params;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api2.php?$args;

        #fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_index api2.php;


        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;


        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include        fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /api1.php?$args;
        fastcgi_index api1.php;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

    }
```

the api files contains slim framework code, when I enter `localhost/getUser/`, the `fastcgi_script_name` will be `rootDir/api1.php`, getUser will be passed into the api1 and show what I expected.
When I enter `localhost/api/lib/v1/getUser/`, `fastcgi_script_name` will be `rootDir/api/lib/v1/getUser` and nothing will show up (404), but when I enter `localhost/api/lib/v1/`, the `fastcgi_script_name` will be `rootDir/api/lib/v1/api2.php`

any ideas what just went wrong here?

Comment: The final element of the `try_files` statement is a URI. You should try: `try_files $uri $uri/ /api/lib/v1/api2.php?$args`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you for your comment, it actually WORKS!